# ThreadPoolExecutor with Context Manager "cannot schedule new futures after shutdown"

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-3.8, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

I'm creating a thread manager class that handles executing tasks as threads and passing the results to the next process step.  The flow works properly upon the first execution of receiving a task, but the second execution fails with the following error :

```
...python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 179, in submit
raise RuntimeError('cannot schedule new futures after shutdown')
RuntimeError: cannot schedule new futures after shutdown
```

The tasks come from `Cmd.cmdloop` user input - so, the script is persistent and meant to not shutdown.  Instead, `run` will be called multiple times, as input is received from the user.

I've implemented a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to handle the work load and trying to gather the results chronologically with `concurrent.futures.as_completed` so each item is processed to the next step in order of completion.

The `run` method below works **perfect** for the first execution, but returns the error upon second execution of the same task (that succeeded during the first execution).

```
  def run ( self, _executor=None, _futures={}, ) -> bool :
     
     task = self.pipeline.get( )
     
     with _executor or self.__default_executor as executor :
         
         _futures = { executor.submit ( task.target.execute, ), }

         for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed ( _futures, ) :
                     
             print( future.result ( ) )
                             
     return True
```

So, the idea is that each call to `run` will create and teardown the `executor` with the context.  But the error suggests the context shutdown properly after the first execution, and cannot be reopened/recreated when `run` is called during the second iteration... what is this error pointing to? .. what am I missing?

Any help would be great - thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually i'm having the same issue, using Process pool context manager in a module of my app that starts a number of processes doing some web-requests.
It seems that the pool module was closed before completing the execution of the process code

Comment: Let me know if you figure anything out for your issue - it may apply to thread pools as well

Comment: have you read through this? https://bugs.python.org/issue40093 Seems like once shutdown is called even if wait is true, it will no longer allow any further futures to be scheduled. Not sure if there is an actual solution to it.

Comment: @AllanElder thanks for the cite.  That seems to suggest the context manager can't be reopened within the same application run instance.  Once it shuts down, it's done - which is strange.  Maybe I need to place the context statement outside the `run` method to keep it persistent?

Answer (score 1):

Your easiest solution will be to use the [multiprocessing library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) instead sending futures and ThreadPoolExecutore with Context Manager:

```
    pool = ThreadPool(50)
    pool.starmap(test_function, zip(array1,array2...))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

While `(array1[0] , array2[0])` will be the values sent to function "test_function" at the first thread, `(array1[1] , array2[1])` at the second thread, and so on.